# Can't edit any objects in method

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a weird problem. I have a tab bar application. When I wanna set the text of an UILabel in any method, there happens nothing.

For example, nothing happens with 'label1' when I call this method:

```
-(void)setOne:(NSMutableArray *)theArray {
label1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label1.text = @"Test";
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Thanks,

Jelle

Comment: have you declare your label1 in .h file?

Comment: have you connect it in interface builder?

Comment: Yes, I have connected it to IB.

Comment: no need to allocate it . try without it.

Answer (score 2):

When you call this method a new label is created and the connection to the label which was previously associated with this ivar is lost. This could also be a memory leak.

Edit:

Depending on the rest of your code, this could work:

```
-(void)setOne:(NSMutableArray *)theArray {
    label1.text = @"Test";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't see anything happened because you create **new instance** of label and do not add it anywhere. If you really want to add new label to your view then create it with appropriate frame and actually add it to some view, e.g.

```
-(void)setOne:(NSMutableArray *)theArray {
   label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 200.0f, 30.0f)];
   label1.text = @"Test";
   [self.view addSubview: label1];
   // And do not forget to release your label!
   [label1 release];
}
```

If you want to change text of label that already exists do not create new instance in your method, just set new text to it:

```
-(void)setOne:(NSMutableArray *)theArray {
   // if label1 already exists we don't need to create a new one
   label1.text = @"Test";    
}
```

**Edit:** (from more info in comments)

When you create view controller it may not load its view immediately so in your code

```
FirstViewController *FVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
[FVC setOne:[resultaten objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

when you call setOne method fvc's view may still not be loaded and label1 is still nil in that method. You can solve that forcing controller's view to load, the following should  work:

```
 FirstViewController *FVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
 FVC.view;
 [FVC setOne:[resultaten objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

But in general I'd suggest to store your values in some class that's independent from UI (i.e. Model) or at least in separate variable of your controller and set it to UI elements only when they actually loaded or appear on screen (in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods)

Comment: Thank you, but this solution does not work. When I tried it, the UILabel did not changed.

Comment: @Jelle how you create your label? if you add it using IB make sure it is properly connected to some IBOutlet in your view controller (make sure it is not nil in setOne method)

Comment: Yes, i added it using IB and connected it to the IBOutlet in my view controller.

Comment: @Jelle, so it is not nil in setOne method? do you call that method from main thread?

Comment: I call this method from another View controller.

Comment: FirstViewController *FVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];

    [FVC setOne:[resultaten objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];                Thats how i call the method.

Comment: @Jelle, if controller is currently offscreen its label1 may be nil even if it is wired on IB, generally it is better idea to store your values in some class that's independent from UI (i.e. Model) and set it to UI elements only when they appear on screen - that's what MVC is about

Comment: Can you try this?Since you are doing this from another View Controller, set this value to a variable where you have the label and set this value to the label in its viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Vladimir I tried your solution, but it did not work. Maybe important: before I call the method in the other view controller, I call:     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
And when I changed this to [self presentModalViewController:FVC animated:YES], my problem was solved. But, I want to dismiss the current view controller and don't have to use [self presentModalViewController:FVC animated:YES]

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 22)];
     lbl.text =@"Hello";
     [self.view addSubview:lbl];
```

}